# Adding an element in object JavaScript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, array

My Question is am displaying the records in Table format and there is a NEW button when it's pressed want to create a new row at the top. With all the fields empty.

Here `doc` contains the record values and `DataFieldValue` contains fieldNames.

> Column are built dynamically. So copying the fieldNames from First Record and Making `doc` Object to null - (say Account)

And making a boolean to true for New record and once the script Runs the New record is inserted and lookup, picklist, input box is created based on fieldName.

But the boolean which was Changed also affects the Second Row(Record) which is `RowItemList[1]` now, after **Javascript unshift**

```
  newRecord :function(component,event,helper){ 

    var RowItemList = component.get("v.currentList");
    var newRow = {"DataFieldValue": RowItemList[0].DataFieldValue, "doc":{}};

    for (var i in newRow.DataFieldValue) {
        for(var j in newRow.DataFieldValue[i].multiFields){
            if(newRow.DataFieldValue[i].multiFields[j].fieldType == "search")
                newRow.DataFieldValue[i].multiFields[j].isrecordineditmode = true;
        }
    }
    RowItemList.unshift(newRow);
    component.set("v.currentList", RowItemList);
 }
```

Suggest the Best way to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex object values are assigned by reference in most languages, including JavaScript. When you do

```
var newRow = {"DataFieldValue": RowItemList[0].DataFieldValue, "doc":{}};
```

`newRow.DataFieldValue` and `RowItemList[0].DataFieldValue` refer to the same object instance. Hence, when you mutate that instance with

```
            newRow.DataFieldValue[i].multiFields[j].isrecordineditmode = true;
```

You are affecting both rows, because their underlying data store is the same object.

Your question doesn't include the actual data type of `DataFieldValue` or its contents, but what you need to do is make a *copy* of that object - a new object, containing the same data -, rather than just assigning it. You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) on Stack Overflow about cloning JavaScript objects helpful.

Comment: Got it still the same Reference - Saved my day, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use functions within your object, a very simple one-liner can be the following:

Stringifying and parsing the object helped to clone the object with a totally new instance

```
var newRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(InsernewRow));
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object#answer-10869248

Answer link credit to @David Reed